# Removing null keys from a json array of objects

Tags: json, jq

I am pulling policies from an azure keyvault

```
policies=$(az keyvault show --name $KeyVaultName --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --query "properties.accessPolicies")
```

Which returns some data like

```
[
  {
    "applicationId": null,
    "objectId": "0123b8ac-57a6-1234-9816-ff5swa4b6d0b",
    "permissions": {
      "certificates": [
        "Get",
        "Release"
      ],
      "keys": null
      "secrets": null,
      "storage": null
    },
    "tenantId": "abc-123"
  },
  {
    "applicationId": null,
    "objectId": "f4340076-d4ea-1234-a719-c75dfsat4d17",
    "permissions": {
      "certificates": null,
      "keys": [
        "Get",
        "Release"
      ],
      "secrets": null,
      "storage": null
    },
    "tenantId": "abc-123"
  }
]
```

Somehow I need to filter out the null permission objects, either by completely removing them or by replacing them with empty arrays. There could be any combination of policies. Is it possible to filter these out? I've been trying variations of jmespath and jq for hours and getting nowhere.

Comment: What do you mean by *null permission objects*?

Comment: "certificates":  null and "secrets":null  and "storage":null should be removed from the second object for example

Comment: current doing some string replacements, but it feels hacky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
del(.[].permissions[] | nulls)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GFLCqz_qxtR)</sup>

Comment: incredible, thanks!